# Explain meaning 'Some things, again, are present in a subject, but are never predicable of a subject' in Aristotle's Categories

Tags: aristotle

> Some things, again, are present in a subject, but are never predicable
> of a subject. For instance, a certain point of grammatical knowledge
> is present in the mind, but is not predicable of any subject; or
> again, a certain whiteness may be present in the body (for colour
> requires a material basis), yet it is never predicable of anything.
>
> Aristotle. Aristotle: The Complete Works (p. 26). Pandora's Box.
> Kindle Edition.

Can you please suggest where is my mistake in understanding:

Thing is either subject or predicate. If A is present in a subject then it is not subject. If it is not subject then it is predicate. But A is never predicable
of a subject.

```
Certain point of grammatical knowledge is present in the mind
```

Certain point of grammatical knowledge is Subject. Present in the mind is Predicate. Why Aristotle uses 'present in a subject' but not 'predicable of some supreme object'?

Comment: See also [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51770/aristotles-meaning-of-present-in-subject)

Comment: According to Aristotle, what is *said of* a subject ("predicable") must be universal, it can be a substance or a property. *Certain* point/ *certain* whiteness are *individual* substance/property, hence not said of anything even when present in it. But grammatical knowledge/whiteness as universals can be said of mind/body. Similarly, *present in* is based on the distinction between substance and non-substance, only non-substances can be present in a subject, see [Predication and Ontology: The Categories](https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/320/cats320.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *property* is un universal, predicable of a subject: "Socrates' hair are white".

Here *whiteness* is predicated of Socrates' hair.

The specific shade of whiteness characteristic of Socrates' hair is a sort of individual property, and thus is not a universal.

Being not a universal, it is not "predicated of" the subject Socrates, but it is "part" of the characteristics of the individual Socrates and thus it is "present in" the subject Socrates.